# Issue accessing state inside setInterval in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to access the state of a component inside a `setInterval` in this way but it's not working:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      console.log(this.state);
    }, 3000);
}
```

However, if I place the callback function in a separate component method, it works perfectly:

```
displayState: function() {
  console.log(this.state)
}
componentDidMount: function() {
    setInterval(this.displayState(), 3000);
}
```

Any idea why is this happening? I would prefer to use the first option.

Comment: The second version works because React ["auto-binds"](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/02/react-v0-4-autobind-by-default.html) methods on components. To make the first version work, `bind` the function as noted in one of the answers.

Comment: you can't call the function on passing to setInterval, that just fires it once immediatly and the interval doesn't do anything. how it works perfectly i dont' get.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In your first example, `this` is out of scope when the callback function fires. One way to solve this problem would be to use a variable:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    var self = this;
    setInterval(function() {
      console.log(self.state);
    }, 3000);
}
```

The problem with your second attempt is that you are calling the function immediately and passing the *result* of executing the function to `setInterval`. You should pass the function itself, taking care to bind the value of `this`:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    setInterval(this.displayState.bind(this), 3000);
}
```

To clarify, the difference between this approach and the second example in your question is that here, a *function* is being passed to `setInterval` (because `function.bind()` returns a function).

As you are using `React.createClass`, it is not necessary to manage the binding of `this` yourself, due to [autobind](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/02/react-v0-4-autobind-by-default.html). This means that you can just pass the function itself and `this` will be the same as in the original context:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    setInterval(this.displayState, 3000);
}
```

Of course, the most suitable approach depends on whether you prefer to use an anonymous function or not.

Comment: a cleaner way to do that while re-using the actual intended method  is  componentDidMount: function() {
  setInterval(this.displayState.bind(this), 3000);
 }, ... (DRY)

Comment: @Tom Fenech What is the difference between that and my second example? It works without `bind`.

Comment: the difference is not having repeated code (console.log), or an extra anon function. if you use an extra anon, then you don't need bind(), you can use the old "that=this" trick: componentDidMount: function() {var that=this; setInterval(function() { console.log(that.state);}, 3000); }

Comment: @dandavis It seems autobind is not working correctly in my one. when I do this componentDidMount: function() {
    setInterval(this.displayState, 3000);
}. state doesn't work in that function. But if i bind it, state does work. Any reason why they autobind is not working? Thanks

Comment: @Mesmerize86 it works in this example https://codesandbox.io/s/xp3or6z4pw (note that I am using React 15 because `createClass` has been removed in newer versions).

Answer (score 5):

You need to execute the interval handler with the correct reference to `this`.
Use React’s **autobinding** for the cleasest solution IMO:

```
displayState: function() {
  console.log(this.state)
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    setInterval(this.displayState, 3000)
}
```

Or use `bind` if you want an anonymous function:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log(this.state)
    }.bind(this), 3000)
}
```

Comment: you cannot bind with curly braces

Answer (score 1):

For the functional syntax this should do the trick of accessing props and state inside an interval function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //run instantly
    functionThatShouldRunEveryTenSeconds(props);

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        //every 10 seconds
        functionThatShouldRunEveryTenSeconds(props);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

You should be able to access everything like state and props as normal.